# How to capture the output of the Pg EXPLAIN command with perl DBI?

Tags: postgresql, perl, dbi

Users of our Mojolicious app can submit queries to our Pg database. Some of these queries can be quite large, both in terms of execution time and number of results returned. I'd like to find a way to run the EXPLAIN command on the query once we generate the appropriate SQL in order to capture the estimated cost and number of rows before deciding to run the query (or warn the user that it's going to be costly).

I don't see a way to use the DBI interface to capture the output of a command like EXPLAIN directly. I could always call the system to run psql and capture the output, but that seems like a lot of extra overhead.

Has anyone tried to do this? It would be handy - Pg will return the results in JSON or XML, which would make it easy to parse.

Comment: Just execute the sql and fetch the result like with a SELECT (or anything else that returns a resultset).

Comment: Thanks - I've tried that interactively and it gives a syntax error.

`# select (explain select distinct eventid from eventlog);

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"

LINE 1: select (explain select distinct eventid from eventlog);`

Am I missing something?

Comment: It should just be `$sth = $dbh->prepare("EXPLAIN SELECT 1+1"); $sth->fetchrow_array()` or something like that

Comment: That works. Many thanks. It also works with `$dbh->selectall_arrayref();`

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me now. Thanks to Richard Huxton for the pointer.

```
my $explain_sql = qq{EXPLAIN (format JSON) } . $sql;
my $h = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref($explain_sql);
warn Dumper($h);
```